# Why compiler telling me its static method when its not?

Tags: c++-cli, static-methods

my myheader.h

```
namespace MyNameSpace{
  public ref MyManagedClass{
      public:
        SomeMemberFunction(String^ FileName, unsigned long SearchScope, [Out] MyCustomFile^ File); // Stripped unnecessary ctor and stuff.
  };
  public ref MyCustomFile{
      public:
        MyCustomFile(MyManagedClass^ parent,NativeFile* hFile);//Implementation doesnt matter
        NativeFile* hFile;
  };
}
```

mycpp.cpp

```
#include "myheader.h"
bool MyNameSpace::MyManagedClass::SomeMemberFunction(String^ FileName, unsigned long SearchScope, [Out] MyCustomFile^ File) {
    HANDLE ManagedHandleIGotFromNativeFunction;
        bool result NativeFunction(&ManagedHandleIGotFromNativeFunction);
    if (result) {
        File = gcnew MyCustomFile(this, (NativeFile*)hFile);// <==== ERROR IS HERE 
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Why building this gives me error

> "Error    C2671    'MyNameSpace::MyManagedClass::SomeMemberFunction': static member functions do not have 'this' pointers."

I never said about this method being static or anything. Why does compiler assume SomeMemberFunction as static?

Comment: The CLI of C++/CLI is **not** command line interface and that tag is not correct.

Comment: idk how it got there. Thanks either way.

Comment: `namespace MyNameSpace{ public ref MyManagedClass{` - there is `ref` term. `bool MyNameSpace::MyManagedClass::` - there is no `ref`. I think so. In the latter case, the compiler treats `MyManagedClass` as a nested namespace.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I suck at writing/understanding C++ code, as simple fix was to declare "MyCustomFile" before using it inside "MyManagedClass".

As It did not find MyCustomFile class declared "SomeMemberFunction" never got compiled and CPP file made its definition as static.

fixed version is below.

myheader.h

```
namespace MyNameSpace{
  public ref MyCustomFile;// <<<<<<<<< Added this Line.
  public ref MyManagedClass{
      public:
        SomeMemberFunction(String^ FileName, unsigned long SearchScope, [Out] MyCustomFile^ File); // Stripped unnecessary ctor and stuff.
  };
  public ref MyCustomFile{
      public:
        MyCustomFile(MyManagedClass^ parent,NativeFile* hFile);//Implementation doesnt matter
        NativeFile* hFile;
  };
}
```

Thanks everyone for your precious time and effort.